# What's wrong with "$in" in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Good day for everyone. I have a strange error working with mongoose

```
module.js:437
  var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, tru
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Dropbox\Dropbox\FCP\server.js
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

I gues it's goes from

```
dbQueries.remove({_id: {$in: {req.body.data}}, authorId: req.user._id}, function onRemoveSomething(err){
            if(err) {
                res.json({epicFail: 'ERR_RestrictedAccess'});
                return; 
            }
        });
```

So, I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[$in](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) takes an array, not an invalidly formatted javascript object

```
{_id: {$in: [req.body.data]}
```

or if `req.body.data` is already an array, omit the wrapping `[` `]`

Comment: Holly syncasis... Thanks a lot

Comment: After a few restarts of node it works fine with {_id: {$in: req.body.data}

Comment: @andy-ray How to do this when req.body.data has one element? Basically the contents of req.body.data can be a single element or an array is the requirement and I am using the in operator. How should I handle this situation?

Comment: Why is this answer being upvoted so much? Is there some tutorial which has the broken syntax listed in the original question?

Comment: stop upvoting this answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to check `req.body.data` is an array or not, see the code below
`{_id: {$in: _.isArray(req.body.data) ? req.body.data : [req.body.data] } //const _ = require('lodash');`

Answer (score 0):

Build your query based on the data

```
var match = {
    authorId: req.user._id
};

if(Array.isArray(data)) {
    match._id = {$in: data};
} else {
   match._id = data;
}

dbQueries.remove(match, function findMyDocs(err, foundDocs) {

});
```