# mongoose.update({$in}

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Recently I asked for **$in** when using mongoose.someModel.find({$in})
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839765/whats-wrong-with-in-in-mongoose"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839765/whats-wrong-with-in-in-mongoose/)

After restarting node for a few times it work correctly as it was originally. But now I found next

```
dbQueries.update({_id: {$in: req.body.data}, authorId: req.user._id}, {deleted: true}, function onUpdate(err){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.json({epicFail: 'ERR_RestrictedAccess'});
                return; 
            }
            res.json({});
        });
```

I found that it updates only first found document! What is happening? I use the last node version and the last of mongoose 2. Moreover it works correctly with mongo-native!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you need to add ['multi' option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-update) in your query.

```
dbQueries.update({_id: {$in: req.body.data}, authorId: req.user._id}, {deleted: true}, { multi: true }, function onUpdate(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({epicFail: 'ERR_RestrictedAccess'});
        return; 
    }
    res.json({});
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Oh, I've been waiting for v.3 api docs for a long time.